# How to use the /testfor command to Locate dyes in Inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to use the /testfor command to Locate dye in Inventory? I am in Minecraft Java 1.12.2. Using The scoreboard tags.
I think this works but not sure.

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dye",tag:{display:{Name:"Elixer"}}}]}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Arqade can't help you unless you can show that you've helped yourself. Please show us some evidence of that, like some sites you've found that didn't help, for example.

Comment: I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Okay, did the command work or not?